# how to prevent edittext focus back to first edittext when devices rotate

Tags: android, view, android-edittext

Let say i have linearlayout with 4 include layout

view_edittext

```
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/il"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/et"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
        </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
    </FrameLayout>
```

activity

```
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <include
                android:id="@+id/layoutET1"
                layout="@layout/view_test"/>
            <include
                android:id="@+id/layoutET2"
                layout="@layout/view_test"/>
            <include
                android:id="@+id/layoutET3"
                layout="@layout/view_test"/>
            <include
                android:id="@+id/layoutET4"/>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Example i'm filling my form, right now focus edittext cursor in layoutET3, but when i rotate the device, the edittext cursor back to layoutET1 again. how to make edittext cursor in correct place like before the device rotate (in this case stick to layoutET3)?

i cant use currfentFocus.id then save it and restore method, because it will cause me same id between 4 included layout

Answer (score 1):

try add

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

for your `Activity` declaration in manifest

this will cause `onConfigurationChanged` method call instead of whole `Activity` recreation, thus should keep your focus on position. more about `configChanges` [HERE](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes)

another approach is to get `id` of currently focused `View` by calling `getCurrentFocus()` when `Activity` is going to be destroyed, store this `id` with `savedInstanceState` and restore after `Activity`s recreation. some guide in [HERE](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states) and I think this would be better approach

Comment: i cant use id from currentFocus because the id is always same between 4 included layout

Comment: well, if you have four `View`s and all have same ids then it would be a problem to manage them... system is storing `id` of `View` with focus when destroying `Activity` and will look for it after recreation. And will found four, so will take first of them and set focus to it... consider differ these `View`s with `setTag` and store this tag with `onSaveInstanceState` instead of `id`

Comment: but how to know which tag that has current focus? can you give me a little example?

Comment: tag them in `onCreate`, e.g. by position in parent `LinearLayout` or some `String` labels. Then you will know by `getCurrentFocus().getTag()` call which view (if any) have focus. Put this tag in `Bundle`, then in next `onCreate` call use `savedInstanceState` to restore previous focused view by tag - you should have tagging-code in onCreate, just call `requestFocus()` when tag to set equals tag restored from `Bundle`

Answer (score 0):

You must be doing something in your Java/Kotlin code that's making it act that way. The focus doesn't change for me when rotating.

Comment: sorry, i'd update my question, the wrong behaviour happened when i used `<include>` layout